# PBR on cisco Switch 3750x for Dual ISP load balancing

Tags: router, switch, switching

I want achieve a load balancing of ISP like the one below.[image: Diagram]

Only 2 subnet should go through ISP 2, and rest of the traffic should go to ISP 1.

Let me know all the things that I need to do on a 3750x core and firewall.
Waiting for your response......

Comment: Just use a route map which matches your subnet using an ACL and set next-hop address (try this doc: http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/catalyst4500/12-2/54sg/configuration/guide/config/pbroute.pdf). There're so many resources on that. What did you try to do?

Comment: HI , Thanks for your reply, what i am trying to do is, that one of my subnet should go through isp 2 and rest all the subnet traffic will go thro isp 1 -- - -  suppose there are  3 subnet (ABC), I want subnet A&B should go through ISP1 and Subnet C will go thro ISP2.

Comment: Then it's exactly described in the document I mentioned above. Create a route-map, match traffic (you create an ACL for that), set next-hop, apply r-m to an interface.

Comment: Thanks, but does it will support on IPBASE 3750x AND ALSO  there are too much on the link, can u give me one sample config of 3 subnet in which 1 subnet for isp 2 and 2 subnets for ISP 1., it will be great help for me

Comment: I think it should, see Cisco's feature navigator. Look for a feature PBR

Comment: Hi Alex, can u paste sample config for above example

Comment: Do you have either a provider independent block of IPs or portable address space?

Comment: Some shameless self promotion here, but [this article on my blog](http://glennmatthys.wordpress.com/2012/04/24/policy-based-routing-example-route-one-subnet-via-isp-a-and-another-via-isp-b/) covers exactly what you want, explained step by step.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

If you only want outbound traffic to be load-balanced like that (beware inbound traffic from the Internet won't be affected and will be routed according to Internet routing tables) then let's suppose your ASA1 IP address is 192.168.0.1/30 and ASA2 address is 192.168.0.5/30.

Two subnets that should go through ISP 2 are:

```
192.168.1.0/24
192.168.2.0/24
```

Everything else goes through ISP1

Then you create two ACLs:

```
access-list 101 permit 192.168.1.0 0.0.0.255
access-list 101 permit 192.168.2.0 0.0.0.255
```

Create a route-map (last permit line is to match all remaining traffic and route by default):

```
route-map pbr1 permit 10
  match ip address 101
  set ip next-hop 192.168.0.5
route-map pbr1 permit 20
  set ip next-hop 192.168.0.1
```

Apply to inbound interface facing the local subnets:

```
interface GigabitEthernet 0/1
  ip policy route-map pbr1
```

Hope that helps a little bit. 
Some more helpful resources for you:

- http://www.ciscozine.com/pbr-route-a-packet-based-on-source-ip-address/
- http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/catalyst4500/12-2/54sg/configuration/guide/config/pbroute.pdf

Also you can see if PBR is supported on your 3750x on [Cisco's Feature navigator](http://tools.cisco.com/ITDIT/CFN/jsp/by-feature-technology.jsp).

Comment: HI Alesx Thanks for the information.....will try to implement and update u.

Comment: Guys, i guess, there is one more imoprtant command: sdm prefer routing. This will tune TCAM buffers for routing purpouses

Comment: Hey I didn't even know about this one!

Comment: currently its default and IP Base image is running so do we need to run this command

Comment: I think this is a decent one on `sdm prefer` command: http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/catalyst3750/software/release/12-2_25_see/command/reference/cr/cli2.pdf

Comment: interface GigabitEthernet 0/1
  ip policy route-map pbr1 - -   Alex  this command will be on Interface vlan ? right ?

Comment: If your Cat3750 is at access level already then you set it on VLAN interfaces for each of those VLANs that should be policed, I think. If your switch goes at layer three further down, then set it on the downlink physical interface

Answer (score 1):

I´m agree with the explanation of Alex, but if you do that, the you must set a modification because if for some reason, one of the two links fails, the pbr mus continue matching traffic, and may occurs that, the traffic flow searching the next-hop of the link down, in other words, a blackhole inside your network.